# Calculate inner product defined by integration

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, inner-products

Let the inner product be defined on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as $$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$$

I am trying to calculate the inner product of $$\langle p, q \rangle = \langle x^2-x + 1/6, x^2-x + 1/6 \rangle$$ but am struggling with how to set this up as an integral for integration. I am not really sure how to factor into one big polynomial so that I can integrate with. What can I do to put this into a solvable integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\langle p, q \rangle = \langle x^2-x + 1/6, x^2-x + 1/6 \rangle$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{1}(x^2-x + 1/6)^2dx$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{1}\left(x^4-2x^3 + \frac43x^2 - \frac13x+ \frac{1}{36}\right)dx$$

Comment: Oh, so there is no better way to simplify the squared polynomials :( thanks! I will be sure to check to make sure I get the same factorization

Comment: I think your answer should be $\frac{1}{3}x^2$ not $\frac{4}{3}x^2$

Comment: @EvanKim - double checked. it is 4/3, which is the sum of 2 terms

Comment: The two terms are $1/6x^2 + 1/6x^2$, there's nowhere in the polynomial where we should be getting any $2/3$

Comment: @EvanKim - my bad. there are 3 terms of $x^2$, 1/6,1/6 and 1. 1 comes from the cross (-x)(-x).

Comment: oh I see what you did. I just left $x^2$ separate from $1/3 \cdot x^2$ but if you combine them, you get $4/3 \cdot x^2$